# Spring Boot OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud

I'm struggling to get my resource server talking to my authorisation server.

This is the config for the my authorisation server.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorisationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("app1").secret("password").authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password", "client_credentials")
                .scopes("openid");
    }

}
```

This is my config for the resource server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@RestController
public class ResourceServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResourceServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

and this is the application.yml for the resource server:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      id: app1
      client-secret: password
      access-token-uri: http://localhost:9999/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: http://localhost:9999/oauth/authorize
```

I can request a token from my AS using the following:

```
$ curl app1:password@localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token -d grant_type=client_credentials
{"access_token":"5e74b3fd-41d2-48a7-a21c-31edf52bcb63","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":43199,"scope":"openid"}
```

Then I use the token to hit my resource API using the following

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer 5e74b3fd-41d2-48a7-a21c-31edf52bcb63" localhost:8080/hello
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: 5e74b3fd-41d2-48a7-a21c-31edf52bcb63"}
```

However I get invalid token and nothing to indicate in the logs, can anyone please help, my feeling is it's the wrong config for the resource server.

Answer (score 0):

Your resource server's application.yml should contain config like this

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:9999/user
```

this user endpoint should expose user details in AS like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Principal user(Principal user) {
    return user;
}
```

This is taken from the [spring security documentation](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/)

Update: Make sure @EnableWebMvc is not used. This doesn't work in case of applications using Spring security since it is [filter based](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html#_filter_based_cors_support)

Comment: There's no need for the user-info-uri. We are using JWT tokens which contains user details.